# Contour Expression to achieve cumulative sum and partitioned sum from same expression

Tags: contour, palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

Cumulative sum and partitioned sum from same expression contour ? Can we achieve this ?

Tried to write this :

SUM("mass") OVER (PARTITION BY "class"
ORDER BY "year" ASC
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS "cumulative_sum",
SUM("mass") OVER (PARTITION BY "class"
ORDER BY "year" ASC
ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING) AS "partition_sum"

Two new columns one with cumulative sum and another with partitioned sum

Comment: Why not as two separate expressions?

Comment: in the last tab of "Expression" you have "aggregate" , in there you can try this.